# Updating Go struct map property

Tags: go, struct

I am proficient in JavaScript and have dabbled in Go. In JavaScript you can modify the properties of an object referenced from an array. But, that doesn't seem to be working in Go.

```golang
type person struct {
    Age int
}

var people map[string]person

func main() {
    people = make(map[string]person)
    people["nick"] = person{Age: 1}
    log.Println(people["nick"].Age)

    nick := people["nick"]
    nick.Age = 2
    log.Println(people["nick"].Age) //Expected is 2, but is actually 1
}
```

I've tried researching the issue on Stack Overflow and a few other sites, but I get bogged down in so many other results. I've also thought maybe it is a problem with pointers, but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 4):

`map[string]person` is a map that contains `person` structs. Thus, when you get a `person` from a map, what you get is a copy of the `person` struct, not a pointer to it. You can either do:

```
 nick := people["nick"]
 nick.Age = 2
 people["nick"]=nick
```

or, convert the map to a pointer map:

```
var people map[string]*person
people = make(map[string]*person)
people["nick"] = &person{Age: 1}
people["nick"].Age=2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I was able to fix the issue with your assistance.